# `eth_estimateGas` with `stateDiff` on a counterfactual smart contract

Tags: gnosis-safe, json-rpc

I have a counterfactual Safe ( v 1.3.0 ) , where funds have been already sent (ERC-20 token). I want to relay a transaction where

1. Safe is being deployed
2. funds are moved out of it

Transaction will be a multitx, meaning that within one call the Safe is deployed and funds are moved.

Since I'm going to relay the transaction, I want to provide the end user with a quote for it. If he accepts it, I then collect the necessary signature to move funds out, and execute the transaction.

To estimate the gas, I could technically use `stateDiff` to manipulate Safe storage when calling `eth_estimateGas` on the RPC node. The problem is I've figured it out that, since the Safe is not yet deployed, the `stateDiff` has no effect.

**Any ideas or hacks on how to solve this problem?**

I was thinking of simulate to separate transaction in a row, but haven't found out if that's possible with a standard RPC node. I know this won't give a super accurate estimation, but still will give a good approximation (< 10% error).

Answer (score 0):

In the safe-wallet web UI we do something similar:

> This estimation is done by calling `eth_estimateGas` with a
> MultiSendCallOnly batch transaction that
>
> 1. Calls the SafeProxyFactory to deploy the SafeProxy
> 2. Call the `simulate` function on the now deployed SafeProxy with the first transaction data.
>    Then we substract a flat gas amount for the overhead of
>    simulating the transaction.

You can view the code here:
https://github.com/safe-global/safe-wallet-web/blob/d21ddd994ef6c904121ce633a44b5070285c7a4c/src/features/counterfactual/hooks/useDeployGasLimit.ts#L59

Maybe this would give you some ideas?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! You mean the `simulateAndRevert` function? Cause the `simulate` one is available in the 4337 compatible version of Safe, correct? 
We thought of `simulateAndRevert`, but we need to make multiple transfers on the same call (using multi sender), so if one reverts, then all the others are not executed.